# Time set through terminal resets after reboot

Tags: 12.04, command-line, date

I set the the time using, e.g.

```
sudo date --set="24 MAY 2013 18:00:00"
sudo hwclock --systohc --utc
```

This worked, but upon reboot the time was back to the old value. What am I doing
wrong? I thought `hwclock` would make it permanent.

I notice in the gui time/date my timezone is still set to a different timezone and 
`Network Time` is set to `on`. So I wonder if it's somehow autosyncing, or if I need
also change the time zone at terminal?

Comment: Where are you? Are you set your Time Zone correctly? Double check it ;)

Comment: The time-zone is currently set to `Europe/Paris`, I want it set to London time. As I mention in the OP, I haven't tried setting the time-zone at all from the terminal, I was just trying to set to time manually with the `date` command (which worked but didn't stay after reboot). Are you suggesting that I also need to somehow adjust the time-zone from terminal too?

Comment: Does time-zone take precedence over the time set via `date`?

Comment: @fpghost... Certainly!

Comment: @fpghost... Ubuntu will update Date/Time using your location info. Therefore Date/Time will be updated on booting operation or some period of time according to your location(TimeZone) using internet services.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To choose your system time zone from a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate [a ntp server like: time.windows.com]
crontab -e -u [your user name]
```

add following job in crontab:

```
@reboot ntpdate time.windows.com
```

save the cron file.